# Technical analysis with python Pyti module - money flow index (MFI)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, technical-indicator

So I'm using pandas, gdax and pyti to calculate Money Flow Index (MFI) for bitcoin.

Here's the code:

```
import gdax
import pandas as pd
from pyti.money_flow_index import money_flow_index as mfi
from datetime import datetime
import time

while True:
    public_client = gdax.PublicClient()
    historic = public_client.get_product_historic_rates('BTC-USD', granularity=60)
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 28)
    df = pd.DataFrame(historic)
    df.columns = ['Time', 'Low', 'High', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume']
    df = df.head(n=28)

    for i in range(len(df['Time'])):
        df['Time'][i] = datetime.fromtimestamp(df['Time'][i]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print(df, '\n')
    close_data = df['Close']
    high_data = df['High']
    low_data = df['Low']
    volume_data = df['Volume']
    period = 14

    mfiDf = pd.DataFrame(mfi(close_data, high_data, low_data, volume_data, period))
    print(mfiDf)
    time.sleep(60)
```

The dataframe has 28 rows, since I'm doing a 14-period calculation.
However, when I run this here's what I get.

```
                   Time      Low     High     Open    Close     Volume
0   2018-03-17 16:48:00  8005.00  8005.00  8005.00  8005.00   0.576900
1   2018-03-17 16:47:00  8000.14  8005.00  8000.14  8005.00   6.063151
2   2018-03-17 16:46:00  8000.14  8000.15  8000.14  8000.15   4.518495
3   2018-03-17 16:45:00  8000.14  8015.01  8015.01  8000.15   7.815928
4   2018-03-17 16:44:00  8015.00  8015.01  8015.01  8015.01   2.937221
5   2018-03-17 16:43:00  8007.34  8020.01  8007.34  8015.01  13.580621
6   2018-03-17 16:42:00  8007.33  8030.99  8030.99  8007.33  13.271350
7   2018-03-17 16:41:00  8030.99  8031.00  8030.99  8031.00   4.746887
8   2018-03-17 16:40:00  8030.99  8031.00  8031.00  8030.99   4.443760
9   2018-03-17 16:39:00  8026.01  8031.00  8026.02  8031.00   4.988071
10  2018-03-17 16:38:00  8026.01  8026.02  8026.02  8026.01   1.370600
11  2018-03-17 16:37:00  8026.01  8026.02  8026.01  8026.01   6.122268
12  2018-03-17 16:36:00  8026.00  8026.01  8026.00  8026.01   2.264600
13  2018-03-17 16:35:00  8026.00  8026.01  8026.01  8026.01   0.514240
14  2018-03-17 16:34:00  8026.00  8026.01  8026.00  8026.01   2.684682
15  2018-03-17 16:33:00  8026.00  8026.01  8026.01  8026.00   3.375641
16  2018-03-17 16:32:00  8026.00  8029.04  8029.04  8026.01   3.406329
17  2018-03-17 16:31:00  8029.03  8034.74  8034.73  8029.04   5.262068
18  2018-03-17 16:30:00  8034.73  8048.66  8048.66  8034.73  11.350111
19  2018-03-17 16:29:00  8048.65  8048.66  8048.65  8048.66   2.447552
20  2018-03-17 16:28:00  8048.65  8048.92  8048.66  8048.66   7.307702
21  2018-03-17 16:27:00  8036.73  8048.66  8036.74  8048.66  18.263245
22  2018-03-17 16:26:00  8025.31  8037.37  8025.32  8036.73   6.869452
23  2018-03-17 16:25:00  8025.31  8033.34  8033.34  8026.89   7.226789
24  2018-03-17 16:24:00  8033.33  8045.44  8045.44  8033.33  12.028749
25  2018-03-17 16:23:00  8016.01  8045.44  8016.15  8045.43  15.495475
26  2018-03-17 16:22:00  8016.01  8018.99  8016.02  8016.16   7.603242
27  2018-03-17 16:21:00  8011.75  8016.02  8011.75  8016.02   8.804586

            0
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3         NaN
4         NaN
5         NaN
6         NaN
7         NaN
8         NaN
9         NaN
10        NaN
11        NaN
12        NaN
13        NaN
14  53.487567
15  51.988001
16  58.553040
17  57.916746
18  56.372137
19  64.919704
20  59.040456
21  42.873900
22  35.009119
23  33.894993
24  42.130290
25  37.090615
26  33.558878
27  31.838329
```

Not quite sure how to read this. My guess is - it does the MFI calculation based on the 14-minute period from 0-13 in order to provide values for 14-27.

I need this to happen the other way around since my original dataframe is ordered by descending time.

Here's how the calculation works inside money_flow_index.py:

```
def money_flow_index(close_data, high_data, low_data, volume, period):
    """
    Money Flow Index.
    Formula:
    MFI = 100 - (100 / (1 + PMF / NMF))
    """
    catch_errors.check_for_input_len_diff(
        close_data, high_data, low_data, volume
        )
    catch_errors.check_for_period_error(close_data, period)

    mf = money_flow(close_data, high_data, low_data, volume)
    tp = typical_price(close_data, high_data, low_data)

    flow = [tp[idx] > tp[idx-1] for idx in range(1, len(tp))]
    pf = [mf[idx] if flow[idx] else 0 for idx in range(0, len(flow))]
    nf = [mf[idx] if not flow[idx] else 0 for idx in range(0, len(flow))]

    pmf = [sum(pf[idx+1-period:idx+1]) for idx in range(period-1, len(pf))]
    nmf = [sum(nf[idx+1-period:idx+1]) for idx in range(period-1, len(nf))]

    # Dividing by 0 is not an issue, it turns the value into NaN which we would
    # want in that case
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=RuntimeWarning)
        money_ratio = np.array(pmf) / np.array(nmf)

    mfi = 100 - (100 / (1 + money_ratio))

    mfi = fill_for_noncomputable_vals(close_data, mfi)

return mfi
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? As far as I can tell, the reverse chronological ordering of `df` is an issue. If that's true, try simply reversing it with `df = df[::-1]` before passing it to `mfi`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I actually tried reversing the dataframe but the numbers were way off when compared to tradingview and cryptowatch. So I figured there must be another problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like reversing the df order is the solution. The difference in the values I get with values from tradingview and cryptowatch seems to come from them working with live data - most likely web socket. I'm working with historic data which comes with a bit of lag. **Thanks Peter Leimbigler!**